# django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, environment-variables, django-settings

When I connect `Postgres` database with `Django`, it gives me following error (screenshot attached either). When I use direct database name or user etc then this work fine but when i use through environment variable, it is not working.

this is my setting.py file:

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',

        'NAME': os.environ.get('DATABASE_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DATABASE_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DATABASE_HOST'),
        'PORT': 5432
    this is my .bash_profile enviroment variable
    
     export DATABASE_NAME='blog'
     export DATABASE_USER='bloguser'
     export DATABASE_PASSWORD='blog@123'
     export DATABASE_HOST='localhost'
```

The error itself:

```
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/kamran/anaconda3/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/kamran/anaconda3/envs/DjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

And the attached image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqrZQ.png

Comment: I'd say use `pdb`(something like `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`) and check that the environment variable is right just before to connect to the database.

Comment: please can you explain

Comment: Tried to explain it in the proper answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can go to the code and place the `pdb` before the `self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)` line, something like:

```py
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
```

Run the server and once it reaches that `pdb` line you could interact with the code in runtime mode, it will show you a `pdb` console and then you can see if that environment variables are setted or not:

```py
(pdb) p os.environ.get('DATABASE_NAME')
(pdb) p os.environ.get('DATABASE_USER')
...
```

It will allow you to see if the variables are setted and with the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL is not running or it's not configured properly.

Change listen_address `localhost to *` in  file  `/etc/postgresql/{version_number}/main/postgresql.conf`

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

In `pg_hba.conf`, add the following line in `# IPv4 local connections`:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

Comment: but when i give the direct username,password and host etc then it work fine